# Getting "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BOOK_PUBLISHERS" not found; SQL statement:"

Tags: java, spring-boot, many-to-many, h2

Using Spring Boot, with Spring Data JPA and H2 in-memory database for process of mapping a many-to-many relationship.

I have two table with entities Book & Publisher. where they many to many relations ship

Created joining table to store the `Book_Id` and `Publisher_id` as foreign keys in `book_publisher` table as below.

```
create table book_publisher 
(
  book_id number not null,
  publisher_id number not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id, publisher_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_bookpublisher_book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES CURRENCY (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_bookpublisher_publisher FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES VENUE (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```

I did not write the domain class for the `book_publisher` table.

But i am getting:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BOOK_PUBLISHERS" not found; SQL
>   statement: insert into book_publisher (book_id, publisher_ID) values
>   (?, ?) [42102-191] " while storting book object(where book class has
>   publisher objects as "SET" variable

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the creation script you mentioned, it'll create a many_to_many relationship between the tables CURRENCY and VENUE. So I would say the code snippet you shared is wrong and this might be why the table BOOK_PUBLISHER was not created successfully.

The right SQL code to create many_to_many relationship (between the tables BOOK and PUBLISHER) should be:

```
create table book_publisher 
(
  book_id number not null,
  publisher_id number not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id, publisher_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_bookpublisher_book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES BOOK (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_bookpublisher_publisher FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES PUBLISHER (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```

Comment: I just changed script as per your comment. Still i am getting same exception.  Table with name "BOOK_PUBLISHER" is created now , but applicaiton still wont insert the records in to that "BOOK_PUBLISHER"  by trowing the error.

Comment: @SatishKonda please share the new error stack trace. It cannot contain the same exception. Your first exception was on table BOOK_PUBLISHER not existing

Comment: In u r Java code can you try table name with same lower case as you created in SQL database may be its case sensitive causing the issue